# Crash when trying to change view programmatically in a pageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to programmatically switch to the next page on a pageViewController. I am using a single contentViewController where I edit the content based on the page index.

Here are my codes:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {




    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as RatingContentView
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 35)

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}



func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> RatingContentView{

    if ((self.pageTitles.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count)) {

        return RatingContentView()
    }

    let vc: RatingContentView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RatingContentView") as! RatingContentView


    if index != 0 {
        vc.name = self.arrayParticipants[index - 1]
        vc.pictureName = self.arrayPictureOfParticipants[index - 1]
    }
    vc.pageIndex = index
    vc.totalCount = self.arrayParticipants.count

    self.indexOfSlide = index

    return vc

}

  func setNextPage() {


    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(indexOfSlide + 1) as RatingContentView
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

      }
```

It does not print any errors in the log, it simply crashes and points the error on this line:
        let vc: RatingContentView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RatingContentView") as! RatingContentView

I have tried many solutions to overcome this, including putting that above line in the viewDidLoad, but none worked.
I am trying to go to the next slide when the function 
      setNextPage()
is called.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking that storyboard is not nil? I don't see where you are setting it. If it is nil you may need to instantiate it before calling instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

Another thing that can trip one up is misspelling the identifier ("RatingContentView") either here or in the storyboard editor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That doesn't solve the issue, I have one on the line:   "self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)   The error is: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Comment: I'm facing the similar issue
self.pageViewController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.baseView.frame.size.width, height: self.baseView.frame.size.height) throws the error : The error is: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.